# styled components final styles are injected directly in DOM with <styles /> tag, with style tag injection does performance gets affected?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

The reason for asking this question was to understand performance impact of styled components , 
So as I have noticed and this is my opinion , that as styled components inject styles in DOM directly via tag ,and does not affect performance that much because even though CSS is written in JavaScript which increases bundle size but that does not matter anyways because browser caches the javascript file and only first time it would affect when file is downloaded , and if not CSS in JS then styles/css file would take that size instead of js file
Only issue could be processing of injecting styles in DOM , but somewhere you have to compromise to gain some benefits because its also a JS library like others

Also with code splitting bundle size divides,

Answer (score 0):

You can find this information in the [documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#issues-with-specificity):

> ... styled-components injects its styles during runtime at the end of the
>   `<head>` by default.

Comment: Hi Lavor , thanks for pointing  i am going through the documentation , Want to know from you are you using styled components for any of your LIVE applications , have you faced any challenges or its a good choice to use it for new projects? from future perspective I wanted an opinion

Comment: Sorry, I am not using them directly, only in some form as a consumer of MaterilaUI. For my own classes, I decided for css modules instead.